# svchost.exe (LocalServiceNetworkRestricted) uses excessive RAM on startup

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, performance, services, memory-leaks

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 with a Core i5 CPU and 4 GB of RAM that I bought July of 2014. Though I have had a good experience, there's one problem, as you can see from the title.

svchost.exe, the service that bundles DLLs, has been acting up recently. Services tied to it have been eating up more and more RAM, leading to 78% RAM Usage **on startup**. I suspect it might be a memory leak, and resetting the computer by holding the power button for more than 4 seconds helps, but I want to fix this problem permanently.

I've tried disabling Superfetch and tracking memory usage---it is definitely svchost that is the problem. Does anyone have any idea what I could do to help with this problem? Again, I suspect it might be a memory leak.

EDIT: @FrankThomas 's comment made me notice that, yes, there's a Nuance Communications audio program running on startup, only I have not determined its name. Also, any troubleshooting features I use or Security Center do not raise any alarms.

EDIT: Could it have something to do with increased McAfee Shield usage? That executable has been using lots of RAM as well.

CLARIFICATION: The RAM usage each time I turn on my computer increases, until the computer cannot function properly and I must reset it using the above mentioned method.

Comment: What happens when you leave the computer alone for a while? Does the resource consumption ever go down? Have you installed the latest updates from Windows Updates? Do you happen to have an nvidia graphics card?

Comment: Most likely it is not a "memory Leak" though only a programmer with access to the code could tell for sure. Memory leaks are generally slow. identify the PID of the process eating all the memory. then run `tasklist /SVC > services.txt`. then check the services.txt file, and find out what system services are running under that particular svchost process. on my system, the only item running under localservicenetworkrestricted are DHCP client, Homegroup, security center, NetBIOS over TCP/IP, eventlog svc, and the windows audio service, I'd check each of those.

Comment: Of those, I'd say Homegroup is a likely culprit. you might want to try exporting your logs, and clearing your eventlog datasources. is security center happy with your current state? do you have an audio player launching on login?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, in fact I do, it's a Nuance product, but it always disappears on startup.

Comment: @Cfinley Windows Updates doesn't say anything about updates, and yes, I've been installing updates as they come. The resource usage doesn't ever go down, and leaving the computer on very slowly increases RAM Usage. Just to clarify, the RAM used on startup increases per startup. Finally, no, I don't have a Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: run a xperf trace which captures the **memory usage grow** and share the file: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't even open more than one tab at a time without causing the browser to crash. I'll try though.

Comment: reboot Windows and run the xperf command to trace the memory usage grow.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's cleared up. I'm really busy right now, so I'll run it as as soon as I have some spare time.

Comment: have you ever captured the trace? Or is the issue gone?